# How can we fetch column values which are between two limits in MongoTemplate?

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

for example i want to find age between 16 and 25 from a collection in mongoDB.
my query is..

```
  Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("visibility").is(1)
.and("type").is("guide").and("age").gte(16).and("age").lte(25));
```

but it is giving exception. reason is mongo template do not support lte() and gte() with same column. so how can i handle it ? is their any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to include an extra `and("age")` part in your criteria. What you need is this:

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("visibility").is(1)
.and("type").is("guide").and("age").gte(16).lte(25));
```

Comment: @DeepakPareek No worries :-)